# Set up invocation of browserify by sbt in build.sbt so that dependencies are bundled on compilation

Tags: java, playframework, sbt, browserify

The scenario, I'm building with Java Play Framework for play-java. I have a dependency that babel compiles to a nasty output line of "var sth = require("sth")".
Apparently browserify is the only hope of getting this nodejs style inclusion to work in the browser. But I don't want to manually call browserify from the CLI on every new compilation. So I found this snippet https://www.toptal.com/scala/using-scala-js-with-npm-and-browserify that is closer to home, but his case was for Scalajs.
So how can I replicate his solution in my scenario?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can execute browserify from sbt by creating a task that executes during the Asset source generation phase.

See this seed project as an example, take a look at the build.sbt for how to create the task: https://github.com/maximebourreau/play-reactjs-es6-seed

Note they deprecated the <+= for appending to the list so you can change the sourceGenerators line to:

`sourceGenerators in Assets +=  browserifyTask.taskValue`

Note this is just executing the browserify binary in the node_modules directory so you have to npm install browserify and running the bablify task but you could change what tasks it executes.

It has also hardcoded the file to browerify `app/assets/javascripts/main.jsx`. You could change this to be a settingKey as well.

The source generators will run anytime you change a file that is in the `sourceDirectory in Assets`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. I will check it out.